# Backward matching in SQLite

Tags: firefox, sqlite

I need to write backward matching query in SQLite. Is there any way to do it?

My example is bellow:

```
SELECT * FROM urls where  forwordurl LIKE '%www.google.com%'
```

that works fine, **but i need to as bellow**

```
SELECT * FROM urls where  'www.google.com' LIKE %forwordurl%
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE 'www.google.com' LIKE '%' || forwordurl || '%'
```

Example:

```
[C:\Temp] :sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table urls (forwordurl text);
sqlite> insert into urls (forwordurl) values ('google');
sqlite> select * from urls where 'www.google.com' like '%' || forwordurl || '%';
google
sqlite> ^Z
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the string concatenation operator in SQLite is not `+`, it's `||`, edited the answer to reflect.